# Eclipse (projeto java) - erro pasta src

Tags: java, eclipse

Espero que possam me ajudar... depois que instalei tudo (tudo mesmo: `ADT`, `Eclpse`, `SDK` e TODAS AS ATUALIZAÇÕES  Android )), não importa quantos projetos eu crie, sempre da erro na pasta `SRC` do eclipse, alguém pode me ajudar...

foto abaixo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou reinstalar o Eclipse? ou instalar outra versão?

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 1):

Botão direito em cima do projeto, Android tools, sdd libraries.
 Vê a versão min e de compile no manifest se bate com as versões que você tem disponíveis de Android pra compilar.

Usa o jar do projeto externo ao invés do projeto em si, e mais pratico.

Use o Android studio, VC evita 60% de problemas

Answer (score 0):

Use o `Android` Studio ele tem suporte total ao `Android` e é passivel da utilização dos plugins da `jetbrains`, o Google não fornece mais suporte ao ADT (plugin do eclipse para desenvolver Android), logo o `ADT` tende a não suportar as novas `APIs do Android` (que atualmente esta na revisão 22).

Nota sobre ADT:

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

Fonte: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html